# HEPA Vacuums for Lead Renovate, Repair, and Paint

Tags: repair, paint, lead

We are starting to clean out an old house that we purchased.

It's a 1939 house so there's probably lead underneath the painted surface.
I plan on doing some [RRP](https://www.epa.gov/lead/renovation-repair-and-painting-program) (renovate, repair, and paint) on my own. And according to the EPA recommendations, we should use [a vacuum with a HEPA filter](https://www.epa.gov/lead/renovation-repair-and-painting-program-do-it-yourselfers)

Is it adequate and safe enough to get a normal shop vacuum and buy HEPA filters for it OR do I have to buy a special HEPA shop vaccum for ~$250 - $300.  Also, is a household vacuum with HEPA filters another alternative?

At the end of the day, I want to get the right protection for me and for my kids when I'm cleaning up.

Answer (score 1):

A HEPA filter on a regular shop vac wil be fine, I wouldn't bother using a household vacuum even with a HEPA filter though.